# Styling the base view of the controller to display a background image

Tags: ios

I am using iOS 6 and I want to have a background image for all of my views. Should I be looking into inheriting from a base class of the view controller and styling the view over there.

Comment: What do mean with 'a background image for all my views'?
One big image spanning the whole screen?

Comment: No I mean I have 20 screens and I want the same background image to appear on all the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would probably be to subclass `UIViewController` and let all the other view controllers inherit from this subclass. In the `viewDidLoad` of the subclass you can programmatically create an `UIImageView` that spans the whole screen and set it`s image property to the image you would like as background.

**Update**
Another easier to implement solution would be to add this to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

Then make sure the main view of each view controller has a clear background.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a solution that doesn't require subclassing, maybe it's easier if you don't need every view controller to be a subclass of ..